# Subscribe to child route changes, Know in parent what child route segment is selected?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**Angular** v2.2.1, **Router** v3.2.1

I have a nested router with children, the router link looks like this:

`/todo/iwgv4ehyav544f7c/zone1`   (`zone1` is the child route of `todo/:id`)

`/todo/iwgv4ehyav544f7c/zone2`   (`zone2` is the child route of `todo/:id`)

*Now keep in mind that `todo/:id` page has it's own router-outlet that displays the children.*

In the parent (`todo/:id`) I have I have 2 buttons, Button1 and Button2.

I want to display Button1 when child route `zone1` is active and Button2 when `zone2` is active.

I have managed to make something but I don't think it is the correct way:

```
   router.events
     .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
     .map(value => value.url.split("/")) // what I get: ["","todo","iwgv4ehyav544f7c","zone1"]
     .map(value => value[3]) // selecting the value at id 3 which is the child param
     .subscribe(response => {
       this.activatedChildUrl = response;  // end value is "zone1"
     })
```

**Is there another better way to subscribe to the router and get the child params, so I can use this value in the parent?**

*Edit:*

Other things I have tried so far that did not work from Victor Savkin book:

```
activatedRoute.url.subscribe(() =>{
  activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.url[0].path

}); // is firing only once
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router has a more simple and elegant solution to determine which path is active and you can hide and show elements depending on the active route.

**Documentation**: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#isActive-anchor

Applied to my project example above:

In TS: `constructor(router: Router){}`

In HTML: `*ngIf="router.isActive('/todo/' + id + '/zone1')"`

You extract the id from your route params or from your selected object.

Answer (score 0):

I like this more:

HTML: `*ngIf="router.url.includes('childroute')"`